# Access Denied while deleting files using docker Windows Nanoserver

Tags: docker, access-denied, nano-server

Command `rmdir /S /Q` is giving `Access Denied` on a Docker image where I am (supposed to be) the same user... why?

Dockerfile:

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809

WORKDIR c:\build
COPY grafana-*.windows-amd64.zip grafana.windows-amd64.zip
COPY grafana-piechart-panel-*.zip grafana-piechart-panel.zip

WORKDIR c:\7zip
ADD 7z1900-x64 .

WORKDIR c:\
RUN c:\7zip\7z.exe x c:\build\grafana.windows-amd64.zip -y
RUN move grafana-* grafana

WORKDIR c:\grafana\data\plugins
RUN c:\7zip\7z.exe x c:\build\grafana-piechart-panel.zip -y
RUN rmdir /S /Q c:\build

WORKDIR c:\grafana
CMD c:\grafana\bin\grafana-server.exe
EXPOSE 3000
```

Output:

```
...
Removing intermediate container ac12af383235
 ---> e5e9b16baf92
Step 12/15 : RUN rmdir /S /Q c:\build
 ---> Running in 25605150cb02
c:\build\grafana-piechart-panel.zip - Access is denied.
c:\build\grafana.windows-amd64.zip - Access is denied.
Access is denied.
The command 'cmd /S /C rmdir /S /Q c:\build' returned a non-zero code: 5
```